# Перенос стиля с Tensorflow, как загрузить локальные изображения?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

В туториале на сайте https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer изображения образца стиля и контента загружаются при помощи строк:

```
content_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg')
style_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'kandinsky5.jpg',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/Vassily_Kandinsky%2C_1913_-_Composition_7.jpg')
```

Как загрузить локальные изображения с диска?

Answer (score 1):

просто пропустите данные строки, т.к. вам не нужно скачивать файлы из сети.

```
content_image = load_img(r"/path/to/image.jpg")
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @RokkenRoll, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа [отметьте ответ как решение и/или проголосуйте за ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)